# How do I get to a chest in lava?

Tags: junk-jack-x

The picture speaks for itself. How do I go about getting to that chest?

[image: Thanks Junk Jack!]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build an iron bucket. Eliminate all lava access points around the chest and then apply the bucket to the lava tile to scoop the lava into the bucket. Then access the chest.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can encrust armor with a ruby and that will make you immune to lava.

Source: http://wiki.pixbits.com/index.php/Encrusting